# Unable to start activity Error: NullPointerException in onCreate

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, syntax-error

when I click on product ListView to see product datail have error! **NullPointerException**

FragmentAllShop.java
onClick listview item will go to detail page

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {  
    int detailshop_id = model.getShop_id();
    String shopID = String.valueOf(detailshop_id);
    Toast.makeText(FragmentAllShopping.this.getActivity(), "Select shopping_id: "+detailshop_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent shopDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), ShoppingDetailActivity.class);
    shopDetail.putExtra("shopID", shopID);
    startActivity(shopDetail);
}
```

ShoppingDetail.java
error on code at line 89 ->                 TitleShop.setText(model.getShop_title());

```
    ShowImgProduct = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ShowImgProduct);
    TitleShop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TitleShop);
    TVPriceDetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVPriceDetail);
    DetailProduct = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DetailProduct);
    TVuserPost = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVuserPost);

    show_shopdetail_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("shopID");
    detailshop_id = Integer.parseInt(show_shopdetail_id);

    JSONParser jspaser = new JSONParser();
    String url = "http://www.leveltistweb09.com/Hello_Oppa/get_shoppingdetail.php?shop_id="+detailshop_id;
    String dataJSON = jspaser.makeHttpRequest(url,JSONParser.methodGet, null);


    try {

        jsOBJ = new JSONObject(dataJSON);               
        int shop_id = jsOBJ.getInt("shop_id");
        String shop_img_url = jsOBJ.getString("shop_img_url");
        String shop_title = jsOBJ.getString("shop_title");
        String shop_price = "ราคา "+jsOBJ.getString("shop_price")+" บาท";
        String shop_detail = jsOBJ.getString("shop_detail");
        String user_display_name = "post by : "+jsOBJ.getString("user_display_name");
        String shop_email = jsOBJ.getString("shop_email");
        String shop_tel = jsOBJ.getString("shop_tel");


        model = new AllShop_Model(shop_id, shop_img_url, shop_title, shop_price, shop_detail, 
                user_display_name, shop_email, shop_tel);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    TitleShop.setText(model.getShop_title());
    TVPriceDetail.setText(model.getShop_price());
    DetailProduct.setText(model.getShop_detail());
    TVuserPost.setText(model.getUser_display_name());

    String path = "http://su13540254.2th.asia/Hello_Oppa/img/";
    ShowImgProduct.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(path+model.getShop_img_url()));
}
```

[error image click!! error on code at line 89 ->               TitleShop.setText(model.getShop_title());](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztrWx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-First of All you have to check whether you are getting ***Json response*** properly or not and then check if response is right then you are **storing in proper object** or not i.e:- ***shop_title*** is not null check here.

-Let me know if issue exist more
Thanks

Comment: i can ask you 1 question ??

Comment: Yes you can ask If you still stuck at the code @JaekohzPark